# Rust Docker-compose `[cargo: not found` Warning While Trying to Build Development Container

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose

I have a bare bones Rust Rocket project that I would like to continue developing using docker-compose. I'v previously used this [Udemy Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/docker-kubernetes-the-practical-guide/) to learn how to set this up with Node.js using Nodemon. My thought is to have a multi stage Dockerfile that sets up all the dependencies then watch my src/ folder for changes and use [Cargo-Watch](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-watch) as a drop in replacement for Nodemon but I'm getting an error with my dev Dockerfile + compose.

`/bin/sh: 1: [cargo: not found`

Here's the compose file with builds my dev container and a postgres db

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  devcontainer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    #   - /app/target/debug
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Here is my Dockerfile.dev that I've been playing with `docker-compose up --build`

```
FROM rust
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-watch
COPY . /app
CMD ["cargo" "watch" "-x" "run"]
```

Here's my working multistage Dockerfile that runs without issue

```
# STAGE 1 - generate a recipe file for dependencies
FROM rust as planner
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

# STAGE 2 - build dependencies
FROM rust as cacher
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json

# STAGE 3 - build source with cached dependencies
FROM rust as builder

ENV USER=web
ENV UID=1001

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    "${USER}"

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=cacher /app/target target
RUN cargo build --release

# STAGE 4 - build docker image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11 as final

COPY --from=builder /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=builder /etc/group /etc/group

COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/auth /app/auth
COPY --from=builder /app/Rocket.toml /app/Rocket.toml

WORKDIR /app

USER web:web

CMD ["./auth"]
```

Comment: Try with `CMD cargo watch -x run` (no quotes and, especially, no `[]`).

Comment: or use commas to separate the arguments: `CMD ["cargo", "watch", "-x", "run"]`

Comment: Please try above suggestions. They seems legitimate.

Comment: @Jmb adding commas in my CMD array fixed this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CMD was missing commas between the commands to execute.

Working command

`CMD ["cargo", "watch", "-x", "run"]`